# DocumentRoot Apache

Tags: apache

Для установки скрипта просит произвести следующие настройки апач:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName your-domain.com
  DocumentRoot /path/to/script/public_html/public;
</VirtualHost>
```

Можно ли такие настройки произвести именно в public_html т.е. только для одного домена?
Что у меня не получается? Не получается установить скрипт в корень домена.

Пока ставлю на OpenServer вот апач настройки:

```
#-----------------------------------------------#
# Начало блока конфигурации HTTP хоста
#-----------------------------------------------#
<VirtualHost *:%httpport%>
    DocumentRoot    "%hostdir%"
    ServerName      "%host%"
    ServerAlias     "%host%" %aliases%
    ScriptAlias     /cgi-bin/ "%hostdir%/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>
#-----------------------------------------------#
# Конец блока конфигурации HTTP хоста
#-----------------------------------------------#

#-----------------------------------------------#
# Начало блока конфигурации HTTPS хоста
#-----------------------------------------------#
<VirtualHost *:%httpsport%>
    DocumentRoot    "%hostdir%"
    ServerName      "%host%"
    ServerAlias     "%host%" %aliases%
    ScriptAlias     /cgi-bin/ "%hostdir%/cgi-bin/"

    SSLEngine    on

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE [1-5].*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE [6-9].*" \
    ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
#-----------------------------------------------#
# Конец блока конфигурации HTTPS хоста
#-----------------------------------------------#
```

Comment: а что именно вас смущает?